# Need to add images and text in a single box in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on creating a fully functioning blog app in Django, but at the moment, I seem lost on how to create a functionality whereby users can use a single textbox to add images, text and videos without creating separate models, which can then be formatted properly using spaces. An example of what I mean is the textarea in Wordpress where all you have to do is type or copy in your text, upload images and videos and format them using the space bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to integrate TinyMCE to Django app for letting users to add images, text and videos.

You need: [django-tinymce](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io)